# AZURE AD - automatically get a refresh token for angular5 web site

Tags: azure, angular5

I am Googling for several days in a row and cannot find anything close to an issue in hand. Users of our web site are required to re-login after 1 hour of inactivity. Business demanded to silently refresh an access token so that users are not requested to login multiple times a day.

How this can be achieved?

Our environment:

AZURE AD - free version

Web site - angular5 and adal-angular5

This is a service (with unnecessary noise removed)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Adal5Service, Adal5HTTPService } from 'adal-angular5';
import { adal } from 'adal-angular';

const config: adal.Config = {
    tenant: environment.tenant,
    clientId: environment.clientId,
    endpoints: environment.endpoints
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private adalService: Adal5Service,
                private httpAdal: Adal5HTTPService,
                private http: Http) {

      this.adalService.init(config);
      this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();

      if (!this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
        this.adalService.login();
      }
    }

    sendRequest(url: string): Observable<any> {
      const resource = this.adalService.GetResourceForEndpoint(url);
      let authenticatedCall: Observable<any>;

      if (resource) {
        if (this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
          authenticatedCall = 
          this.adalService.acquireToken(resource).flatMap(token => {
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

            return this.http.request(url, headers)
          });
        } else {
           this.adalService.login();
        }
     }

     return authenticatedCall;
  }
}
```